# Is there an 'or' notation in qmake

Tags: qt5, qmake

I am using `win32`, `macx` and `unix:!macx` aka. Linux if statements in my `.pro` file, to specify os specific tasks, e.g.

```
win32 {
    TARGET = myapp
    RC_FILE = myapp.rc
}
macx {
    TARGET = MyApp
    ICON = myapp.icns
    QMAKE_INFO_PLIST = Info.plist
}
unix:!macx { # linux
    CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
        TARGET = myapp-debug
    }
    CONFIG(release, debug|release) {
        TARGET = myapp
    }
}
```

This works fine for `if X else`, `if X elseif X else`, and `if not X` where `X` is an os specifier.

Is there a way to tell qmake it must compile a block for `os1` or `os2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `|` operator for a logical `or`. For example:

```
win32|macx {
    HEADERS += debugging.h
}
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html

Comment: Great, thanks. It turns out that `|` binds stronger than the `:` operator. This can be worked around using the undocumented and operator `&`. E.g. `unix | macx&CONFIG(release, debug|release) {` runs on Linux debug where `unix | macx:CONFIG(release, debug|release) {` does not.

Comment: Forget my last comment. There is no operator `&`. The part of the line was just not parsed because `unix` was `true`.